# How a RNN can learn given the number of weights it contains?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently learning neural network and especially RNN and this might sounds like a basic question but RNNs have much more weights than a feed-forward, so how it succeed to learn? Indeed, a LSTM cell, for instance, has one fully connected per gate which all contains weights for both the input and the previous state, whereas a feed-forward has only one time the weights for the input.

Does it learn because RNN are usually used for NLP, where there may be lot of data? Does the RNN architecture allows to use less neurons than a feed-forward which compensate? or maybe I just did not understand well the RNN and LSTM cell?

**EDIT:** I think I got mixed up. here is why. When training a feed-forward deep neural network there is a point where it is difficult to train, but is it due to the number of weights or the number of layer it contains? Indeed, when there is a lot of layer, the early layers' weights may get a very little amount of variation as the errors as to be propagated backward through all the networks. But is the total number of weights contained in the networks also playing a role in the difficulties to train it, independently of the number of layer? Because I first thought that the unserw is yes (which explain my question about RNNs), but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: RNN training method is a variation of FF ANNs, ie backpropagation adjusted with time delays. So there is no mystery how it learns during training. That being said, RNNs are more unstable than LSTMs

Comment: https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/whirlwind-tour-of-rnns-a11effb7808f

Comment: I understand how it is trained, but out of that, there is still more weights than FF ANNs for each neurons (without concidering the "enrolling though time"). It seems to me that RNN/LSTM will face training difficulties earlier than FF.